# Regex doesn't match in c but works with online interpreter

Tags: c, regex

I have a regex that I have tested with https://regexr.com/, where it works correctly. But in c it doesn't find any match.

My code is below; I have removed everything unnecessary.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <regex.h>  
int main ()
{
    char * str = "<sql db=../serverTcp/Testing.db query=SELECT * From BuyMarsians;\>";
    char * regex = "<sql\s+db=(.+)\s+query=(.+;)\s*\\>";
    regex_t regexCompiled;

    if (regcomp(&regexCompiled,regex,REG_EXTENDED))
    {
        printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    };
    if (!regexec(&regexCompiled,str, 0, NULL, 0)) {
    printf("matched");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    regfree(&regexCompiled);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The regex test site you link supports only the Javascript and PCRE / Perl regular expression dialects.  The C regex API you are using implements the POSIX basic and extended regex dialects (of which you are using the latter).  Therefore, the web site is not a reliable predictor of what you should expect from your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes. Change

```
char * regex = "<sql\s+db=(.+)\s+query=(.+;)\s*\\>";
```

to

```
char * regex = "<sql\\s+db=(.+)\\s+query=(.+;)\\s*\\\\>";
```

Note that this is extremely inefficient. A much more efficient regex uses non-greedy quantification, with `?`:

```
<sql\s+db=(.+?)\s+query=(.+;)\s*\\>
//           ^ key change
```

That becomes:

```
char * regex = "<sql\\s+db=(.+?)\\s+query=(.+;)\\s*\\\\>";
```

Also note: Your string to be matched also includes `\`. You need to escape it there, too:

```
char * str = "<sql db=../serverTcp/Testing.db query=SELECT * From BuyMarsians;\\>";
```

Here's a [**working demo of your corrected code**](https://ideone.com/2p4Nxk).

Comment: still dosen't working sir : console : root@kali:~/Desktop/ClientServerTcp2/serverTcp# ./test
NOT matched

Comment: Needs more than that; OP's regular expression library doesn't support things like `\s` for whitespace.

Comment: it's interesting because this two works :     char * str = "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1";
    char * regex= "^GET\\s([^\\?\\*<>|]+)\\sHTTP"; ... this works

Comment: @Singh Your problem is that your string to be matched also includes ```\```. You need to escape it there, too.

Comment: @Shawn Sure it does, if the ```\``` is properly escaped. See [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/7Nb0kS).

Comment: @Singh I've added a link to a working demo; see my revised answer above. Also, just FYI: I've noticed that you've typed "dosen't" several times. For future reference, it's "doesn't." Languages are hard. :)

Comment: char * str = "<sql db=../serverTcp/Testing.db query=SELECT * From BuyMarsians;\\>"; -> what if i cannot add \ to escape \ in the string ? is there any alternative or i have to add it?

Comment: @Singh If you are getting that string as a literal from somewhere else (a file, an API, whatever) then you don't need to escape it. If you are typing it directly into your c code, you will need to escape it to produce the same string. In other words, if you have a file containing ```a\b```, your program would read it in as ```a\b``` (unless you're doing something very strange). But to hard-code that in c, you would need `char * myString = "a\\b";`. I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot sir. my bad with doesn't,from now i'll read before pressing enter. thanks again

Comment: It looks like glibc's implementation of `regcomp()` does recognize `\s` as an escape sequence representing a whitespace character, but that is non-conforming.  POSIX regexes do not have that feature, and glibc's `regcomp()` is documented to implement POSIX regular expressions (by both POSIX and glibc itself).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point. It seems to include both POSIX features and some PCRE features. For reference by other readers who may stumble across this, I find [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (no affiliation) very helpful in understanding different flavors of regex syntax (among other things).